# Send parameter type over ajax (Spring/Jackson)

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Trying to send parameter type to controller but keep failing. As result of this example I`m getting *"It is String"*.

My Class:

```
public class FieldCriteria<T>
{
    private SearchParam searchParam;
    private SearchOperand operand;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Integer.class, name = "java.lang.Integer"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = String.class, name = "java.lang.String"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Boolean.class, name = "java.lang.Boolean"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Date.class, name = "java.util.Date"),
                    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = List.class, name = "java.util.List") })
    private T value;

    @JsonCreator
    public FieldCriteria(@JsonProperty("searchParam") SearchParam searchParam,
        @JsonProperty("operand") SearchOperand operand, @JsonProperty("value") T value)
    {

        this.searchParam = searchParam;
        this.operand = operand;
        this.value = value;
    }
    //getters/setters
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/display_filtered_criteria", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public FieldCriteria displayFilteredCriteria(@RequestBody FieldCriteria fieldCriteria)
{

    if (fieldCriteria.getValue() instanceof Date)
    {
        System.out.println("It is Date");
    }
    else if (fieldCriteria.getValue() instanceof String)
    {
        System.out.println("It is String");
    }
    else if (fieldCriteria.getValue() instanceof List)
    {
        System.out.println("It is List");
    }
    else if (fieldCriteria.getValue() instanceof Integer)
    {
        System.out.println("It is Integer");
    }
    else if (fieldCriteria.getValue() instanceof Boolean)
    {
        System.out.println("It is Boolean");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unknown type");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Javascript:

```
fieldCriteria = {
    'searchParam': null,
    'operand': null,
    'type': 'java.util.Date',
    'value': new Date()
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'display_filtered_criteria',
    data: JSON.stringify(fieldCriteria),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', _csrf);
    },
    success: function (r) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

I would like to set parameter **value** in class **FieldCriteria** dynamically.
Is it possible and is my approach right ?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "*keep failing*"? What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Updated question with: As result of this example I`m getting "It is String".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to solve it by changing class annotations and json structure before sending. Here is a solution.

Class from:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
```

Class to:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

(property = "type" is not needed for JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)

And working JSON:

```
fieldCriteria = {
    'searchParam': null,
    'operand': null,
    'value': {'java.lang.Date': new Date()}
};
```

Also tested with Boolean and other types. In controller I`m getting right value type.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you written a test to proof that the deserializer works as you expect? I cannot write one right now, but I don't know if it's really working. I ask just because I've the feeling that it's not ok (having a background in c#, I get burned more and more times by generics in Java...).

By the way, I think you could obtain the same result using the type of the parameter in the controller to select a different function. In fact you can write something like this (only with Spring 3.2 and after, before it's not working):

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/display_filtered_criteria", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    params = {"type=java.util.Date"} )
@ResponseBody
public FieldCriteria displayFilteredCriteria(
    @RequestBody FieldCriteria<Date> fieldCriteria) {
    ... 
} 

@RequestMapping(
    value = "/display_filtered_criteria", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    params = {"type=java.lang.String"} )
@ResponseBody
public FieldCriteria displayFilteredCriteria(
    @RequestBody FieldCriteria<String> fieldCriteria) {
    ... 
} 

// others to follow
```

You will have cleaner code and you don't have to worry about the deserialization of the generic type.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but can`t accept this approach because class FieldCriteria is not standalone class (it is part of a nested object).

Comment: No problem! I didn't know the whole background. 
I would suggest you to write this also in the Documentation, if it's possible with a whole code example.